# How to fix "Coordinate{\$CellContext`x1, \$CellContext`y1, \$CellContext`z1} should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d, animation

I have a program which should show the motion of N particles in an electric field as a function of time and position within the field. I am running into the aforementioned error (listed in title) when it comes time to display everything in the final lines of the code:

```
frames = Table[
   Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, 
       numbodies}], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
    Graphics3D[
     Table[{Hue[.35], 
       Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
       numbodies}]]], {tf, .025*tfin, tfin, .025*tfin}];
video = ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

The animation window is kind of highlighted red and doesn't show the particles or electric field at all. I haven't found a solution which directly addresses this error in my particular context, but I could be missing something. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Here is the full code.

````
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

q = 1.617733*10^-18;(*Net ion Charge*)

R= Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds8rm3odg2m7gu/largeAp.obj?dl=\
1"];

RegionDimension[R];
M = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
RegionDimension[M];
Volume[M];

r = RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -0.5}, {2, 2, 0.5}], M], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.4}, {2, 2, 0.5}]], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, -0.5}, {2, 2, -0.4}]];
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"];
pol = -1;

V0 = 15000;
sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == -pol*
       V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <=
         2)], DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (-0.5 <= z <= -0.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)]}, 
   V, {x, y, z} \[Element] r];

electricField[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

v = Show[VectorPlot3D[
    electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.1}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorScale -> 0.03, 
    VectorPoints -> 7], M];


vecForce = 
  Show[VectorPlot3D[
    q*electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 
     1}, {z, -0.25, -0.00001}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    VectorScale -> 0.05, VectorPoints -> 7], M];



numbodies = 3;
mass = 6.52*10^-11;(*particle mass in kg/m^3*)


vel0 = Table[Partition[{0, 0, 0}, 1], numbodies];
(*vel0=Table[Partition[{RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.\
0001,0.0001}],RandomReal[{-0.0001,0.0001}]},1],numbodies]*)
pos0 = Table[
   Partition[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-0.4, -0.04}]}, 1], numbodies];

eforce1 = -q*(Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]);
tfin = 200;

eforceX = (eforce1[[1]] /. {x -> x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], 
    z -> z1[j][t]})
eforceY = (eforce1[[1]] /. {x -> x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], 
    z -> z1[j][t]})
eforceZ = (eforce1[[1]] /. {x -> x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], 
    z -> z1[j][t]})
(*
eforceX =(eforce1[[1]]/.{x\[Rule]x1[j][t], y\[Rule]0,z\[Rule]0})
eforceY=(eforce1[[1]]/.{x\[Rule]0, y\[Rule]y1[j][t],z\[Rule]0})
eforceZ =(eforce1[[1]]/.{x\[Rule]0, y\[Rule]0,z\[Rule]z1[j][t]})*)

eqs = Table[{x1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceX[[1]],
    y1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceY[[1]],
    z1[j]''[t] == -(1/mass)*eforceZ[[1]],
    x1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 3, 1]],
    x1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 1, 1]],
    y1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 2, 1]],
    z1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 3, 1]]},
   {j, numbodies}];
vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]}, {j, numbodies}]];


event = Table[{WhenEvent[
      z1[j][t] == -0.025, {x1[j]'[t] -> 0, y1[j]'[t] -> 0, 
       z1[j]'[t] -> 0}]} /. j -> i, {i, numbodies}];



sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, vars, {t, 0, tfin}]
sol1 // OutputForm


plotXZ = ContourPlot[sol[x, 0.75, z], {x, 0, 2}, {z, -0.4, 0.1}, 
   ContourShading -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Contours -> 100];


frames = Table[
   Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, 
       numbodies}], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
    Graphics3D[
     Table[{Hue[.35], 
       Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
       numbodies}]]], {tf, .025*tfin, tfin, .025*tfin}];
video = ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```
````

Comment: That's a lot of code! You need to do some troubleshooting on your own. Starting towards the end, comment pieces out until you can pinpoint where the problem originates in your code, and then re-focus your question on that piece, with a smaller and more manageable example.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry, I should have been more specific. Everything appears to be fine up until the last small block of code at the very bottom: `frames = Table[
  Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
    Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, numbodies}], {t,
      0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
   Graphics3D[
    Table[{Hue[.35], 
      Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
      numbodies}]]], {tf, .025*tfin, tfin, .025*tfin}];
video = ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]`

Comment: Right, so `video` depends on `frames`, so are the frames generated correctly? Comment out the `video` part and run up to `frames`, then run for example `frames[[1]]`. Does that give you the same error? If it does, then dig into the `Table` expressions. Comment out the `Graphics`, or the `ParametricPlot`. Does the error go away? Follow this method until you find where the error is introduced. Once you get there, you may also find a way to fix it too :-)

Comment: Best to use `First` on `sol1` as shown in the docs. Less obvious in the docs but a common piece of advice here is to get the solution from `NDSolve` in function form instead of expression form: Try `sol1 = First@NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}];`

Comment: You seem to include a couple of unused plots. They should have been deleted from the code. The code should not have extraneous pieces that have nothing to do with the problem. Note that your particles hardly move, so that there is little point to the `ListAnimate`.  Or perhaps you need only increase `tfin`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 using `Head /@ vars` in my sol1 expression fixed the graphing problem!

Comment: @zak720 Great! I usually set my `vars` up without the `[t]`: `vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j], y1[j], z1[j]}, {j, numbodies}]];`.  If I need the `[t]` added, then I use `Through[vars[t]]`.  But the other way, your `vars` with the `[t]` and `Head /@ vars` to remove them, works, too.